# Using a function in Python to compare timestamps (with Delorean)

Tags: python

I have a basic piece of Python code in which I'm trying to compare one time to another (I have to admit I'm a bit new to python). I'm using Delorean to convert the string to an epoch integer and to compare it to a variable `lastTime`. The rest of my code works, but as soon as I try to add in the new function my readout goes blank. I'm struggling with this as Python isn't throwing any errors, it's just giving me nothing.

Here's the code in its entirely:

```
import random,sys,csv, delorean
from collections import defaultdict
from delorean import Delorean
from delorean import parse

size = ['small','medium','large']
color = ['blue','red','green']
body = ['fish','squid']

fishparts = defaultdict(set)
lastfish = defaultdict(str)
lastTime = 0


def tenMinInterval(ts, lt): # HAVING PROBLEMS HERE
    global lastTime
    curTime = Delorean(ts).epoch()
    if curTime > lt+600000: # timestamp is a string and lastTime is an int
        # return True
        lastTime = curTime
        return 'Upadted Time'
    else:
        # return False
        return 'Not Upadted'

def complexityFish(ps,pf):
    score = 1
    if ps == 'medium':
        score += 1
    elif ps == 'large':
        score += 2
    if pf == 'squid':
        score += 2
    return str(score)

def diffPrev(a,la,b,lb,c,lc):
    score = 0
    if a != la:
        score += 1
    if b != lb:
        score += 1
    if c != lc:
        score += 1
    return str(score)

def diffUniq(player,x):
    score = 0
    for e in x:
        if e not in fishparts[player]:
            score += 1
        fishparts[player].add(e)
    return str(score)


def parseOneFish(p_player,p_fish):
    player  = p_player
    fish    = p_fish
    if lastfish[player] != '':
        ls,lc,lt = lastfish[player].split(' ')
    else:
        ls = lc = lt = ''
    s,c,t = fish.split(' ')
    lastfish[player] = fish
    return((complexityFish(s,t),diffPrev(s,ls,c,lc,t,lt),diffUniq(player,[s,c,t])))


csvfilename = sys.argv[1]
csvdata = csv.DictReader(open(csvfilename,'rb'),delimiter=',')
x = False
for line in csvdata:
    if not x:
        print ','.join([k for k in line]),
        print ',complexity,diffprev,diffuniq'
        x = True
    try:
        cx,dp,du = parseOneFish(line['playerID'],line['fishType'])
        tm = tenMinInterval(line['timestamp'], lastTime) # HAVING PROBLEMS HERE
        print ','.join([line[k] for k in line]) + ',',
        print ','.join([cx,dp,du])
        print ','.join(tm)
    except:
        print ''
```

The parts I'm struggling with are in the function `tenMinInterval` and at the bottom at `tm = tenMinInterval(line['timestamp'], lastTime)`
I know the return isn't doing much right now but that shouldn't bork the rest of it correct?

Here's a sample of my [csv file as well](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4jJ-Gqm65YJdVU2X21hWnYyTU0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: If you need the difference between `timestamp` and adjusted timestamp` , why not use `excel` (or `googlesheets`) to do the computation for you? Sounds MUCH easier

Comment: I guess `tenMinInterval` raises some exception and then the `print ''` in the exept clause is executed, filling your screen with blank lines. Replace `print ''` by `raise` to see what's going on. In general it is a good idea to list the types of exceptions you want to catch (e.g. `except IOError`), so you don't accidentally catch anything you didn't anticipate.

Comment: @letsc because I'm going to be pulling in some cases +10,000 items and it's prohibitive to do that (and manually pulling it down and editing and then manipulating it in python adds a bunch of steps that should be easy to do in python)

Also I want to do a lot more with it once I figure out the difference - this just gets me to the next step

Comment: @mkrieger1 - Thanks I used `raise` to get the error I needed! It ended that I needed to do another parse because of way my DB was formatting my timestamp. Seems to be working now (or at least I'm on to my next problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks to mkrieger1 I was able to check my errors better and it ended up being a parsing problem with how my DB structured the date and how Delorian default reads it.

Here's the function fixed:

```
def tenMinInterval(ts, lt):
    global lastTime
    strTime = delorean.interface.parse(ts, dayfirst=False, yearfirst=False)
    curTime = strTime.epoch()
    print curTime
    if curTime > lt+600: # timestamp is a string and lastTime is an int
        # return True
        lastTime = curTime
        print 'Time Updated'
    else:
        # return False
        print 'Time not Updated'
```

In case anyone needs it there's an explanation of parsing dates [here](http://delorean.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#strings-and-parsing) and [here](http://delorean.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interface.html#delorean.interface.parse). While tinkering I also needed to add `from delorean import epoch`